# Colour issue while working with an 8-bit image which has been modified using the canvas object and uploaded to the server

Tags: javascript, c#, html, image-processing, canvas

**Overview:**

I have an app which allows customers to upload an image - a photo.  To reduce the number of bytes I send to the server, I reduce the size of the image using HTML5 canvas.  There are specific needs and known size requirements for the photo so I perform further resizing on the server, storing each image into blob storage.

The problem I'm experiencing is specific to an 8-bit greyscale image, *all the white pixels are coloured red.*

**The steps:**

1. Using the current version of Chrome, a customer selects a photo to
           be uploaded.
2. The client uses a JavaScript library called [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) to resize the image to a maximum size fitting within a 2048px box at 70% quality. A canvas object is returned.
3. A blob is created from the canvas using canvas.toBlob() and sent to the server.
4. The server receives the uploaded bytes which are streamed to disk.
5. Once complete the file is loaded via the Image class.
6. The image is saved to blob storage as the 'original'
7. The image is resized and saved to blob storage as 'main'

**Key finding:**

Only the server resized image in step 7 contains the problem.

The original Image saved in step 6 doesn't have its white pixels converted to red.  For completeness the Image class is converted to a MemoryStream and uploaded to Azure Storage, as are the resized images.

If I skip the client-side resize I don't have an issue with white pixels turning red.

Looking at the properties of the image (via Windows) which was streamed to disk in step 4, I can see the image has a bit depth of 24.  Doing the same with the original displays 8.  This makes sense as the Canvas object will only work with a 24 bit image which I believe is taken from the screen.

*So it appears the problem is specific to a 8 bit image which has been converted to 24 bit via the Canvas object and has subsequently been resized on the server*

**What I've tried so far:**

I've concentrated my efforts on the server so far as it appears I have little options on the client.

As you'd imagine my 'initial' code for resizing an image on the server is faily straight forward 'out of the box' stuff.

```
var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
```

I've also tried using the Graphics object for more control.  I've played with each of the quality / mode parameters - happy to try more.  I've also tried...

```
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
```

In case I was starting with a red canvas and the white was actually a transparent.

Finally I tried 2, C# image processing libraries to replace my own server-side resize code.  These where [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) and [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/). Both gave the same results.

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually red, and not just transparent with red behind it?